# Event firing twice in kendo collapsible

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, event-handling, jquery-events, openedge

I have an app the uses the Progress JSDO to load data and, using the foreach method of the jsdo, append the data to three different lists in kendo collapsible panels depending on the status of one of the fields. For some reason, the lists are being appended twice in the code and I can't figure out why. I would appreciate another set of eyes on my code to help me get to the bottom of this mystery.

Here is the controller for the view (this is all wrapped in an IIFE with some other code, but this is the relevant section.):

```
app.scanBarcode = {
    viewModel: new ScanViewModel(),
    onShow: function () {
        app.JSDOSession.addCatalog(app.JSDOSettings.catalogURIs);
        app.locJSDO.fill();
        $("#list-button").unbind().click(function () {
            app.goToScanFail();
        });

        app.scanBarcode.getCurrentReport();
    },
    onHide: function () {
        var reportJSDO = app.reportJSDO,
            writeOutReport = app.scanBarcode.writeOutReport;
        reportJSDO.unsubscribe('afterFill', writeOutReport);
    },
    getCurrentReport: function () {
        var reportJSDO = app.reportJSDO,
            writeOutReport = app.scanBarcode.writeOutReport;

        //Fill the JSDO from db and call function to  display the data
        reportJSDO.subscribe('afterFill', writeOutReport);
        reportJSDO.fill();
    },
    writeOutReport: function (jsdo, success, request) {
        var date = app.getDate();
        jsdo.foreach(function (report) {
            var reportDate = report.data.STAMP_DT,
                completed = "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span>",
                notCompleted = "",
                span;
            if (reportDate == date) {
                if (report.data.STAMP_TM == null) {
                    span = notCompleted;
                    $("#uncompleted-list").append(
                        "<li class='list-group-item'>" +
                        span + " " +
                        report.data.LOCATION_ID +
                        ' ' +
                        report.data.LOCATION_NAME +
                        "</li>"
                    );
                } else {
                    span = completed;
                    $("#completed-list").append(
                        "<li class='list-group-item'>" +
                        span + " " +
                        report.data.LOCATION_ID +
                        ' ' +
                        report.data.LOCATION_NAME +
                        "</li>"
                    );
                }

                $("#all-list").append(
                    "<li class='list-group-item'>" +
                    span + " " +
                    report.data.LOCATION_ID +
                    ' ' +
                    report.data.LOCATION_NAME +
                    "</li>"
                );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the html for my view:

```
<div data-role="view" data-title="Scan Location" data-reload="true" data-layout="views-layout" data-model="app.scanBarcode.viewModel" data-show="app.scanBarcode.onShow" data-hide="app.scanBarcode.onHide">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h3 class="hassubtitle">Begin Scan:</h3>
    <button class="btn btn-xlg btn-primary btn-block" data-bind="click: scan">Scan</button>
    <button id="list-button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block">Skip</button>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="completed-collapsible">
        <h2>
            Completed
        </h2>
        <div data-role="scroller" id="completed-list"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="uncompleted-collapsible">
        <h2>
            Uncompleted
        </h2>
        <div data-role="scroller" id="uncompleted-list"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="all-collapsible">
        <h2>
            All
        </h2>
        <div data-role="scroller" id="all-list"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm the only web developer at my work and I have no one to ask here, so I really appreciate you all!

Comment: Did you try to unsubscribe the after-fill event at the very beginning of the writeOutReport function?

Comment: I apologize for my confusing code. writeOutReport actually is onAfterFill, I never went back and changed the names after moving some code around. I have edited the original post to include the proper function names.
BUT, I did try your suggestion anyway and it did not work haha.

Comment: I see that. But the very first thing in that method should be to unsubscribe the event.